# LWJGL Colors messed up when using textures + lower FPS when disabling texturing often

Tags: java, opengl, colors, textures, lwjgl

I initially had a problem of messed up colors when using texturing but I managed to fix it (the problem was I wasn't disabling texturing when needed). After doing that, the colors changed but are still not the ones I'd wish to - white instead of pure blue (0,0,255) RGB.
Here is the complete rendering method:

```
private void render() {

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
    GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The View

    GL11.glRotatef(lookupdown, 1.0f, 0, 0);
    GL11.glRotatef(360.0f - yrot, 0, 1.0f, 0);

    GL11.glTranslatef(-xpos, 0, -zpos);



    /*                   RENDERING BLOCKS                      */
    for (Block block : lvLoader.currentLevel.blocks)
    {
        if (block.created)
        {
            if (block.texturePos != null)
            {
                if (block.texturePos.pos != -1)
                {
                    Texture txt = TextureManager.getInstance().blocks[block.texturePos.pos];
                    if (txt != null)
                    {
                        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, txt.getTextureID());
                    }
                }
            }

            GL11.glColor3ub(block.color.getRedByte(), block.color.getGreenByte(), block.color.getBlueByte());
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                {
                    if (block.texturePos != null)
                    {
                        switch (j)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    GL11.glVertex3f(block.walls[i].vertices[j].x, block.walls[i].vertices[j].y, block.walls[i].vertices[j].z);
                }
            }



            GL11.glEnd();

            //if (block.texturePos != null)
                //if (block.texturePos.pos != -1)
                    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
    }


    /*                   RENDERING TILES                      */
    for (Tile tile : lvLoader.currentLevel.tiles)
    {
        if (tile.created)
        {
            if (tile.texturePos != null)
            {
                GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                if (tile.texturePos.pos != -1)
                {
                    Texture txt = TextureManager.getInstance().tiles[tile.texturePos.pos];
                    if (txt != null)
                    {

                        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, txt.getTextureID());
                    }
                }
            }

            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glColor3ub(tile.color.getRedByte(), tile.color.getGreenByte(), tile.color.getBlueByte());


            for (int jj = 0; jj < 4; jj++)
            {
                if (tile.texturePos != null)
                {
                    switch (jj)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                } 

                GL11.glVertex3f(tile.surface.vertices[jj].x, tile.surface.vertices[jj].y, tile.surface.vertices[jj].z);
            }



            GL11.glEnd();

            //if (tile.texturePos != null)
                //if (tile.texturePos.pos != -1)
                    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
    }


    /*                   RENDERING ROOF                      */ 
    for (Tile rTile : lvLoader.currentLevel.roof)
    {
        if (rTile != null)
        {
            if (rTile.created)
            {
                if (rTile.texturePos != null)
                {
                    if (rTile.texturePos.pos != -1)
                    {
                        Texture txt = TextureManager.getInstance().tiles[rTile.texturePos.pos];
                        if (txt != null)
                        {
                            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, txt.getTextureID());
                        }
                    }
                }

                GL11.glColor3ub(rTile.color.getRedByte(), rTile.color.getGreenByte(), rTile.color.getBlueByte());
                GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                {
                    if (rTile.texturePos != null)
                    {
                        switch (k)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    GL11.glVertex3f(rTile.surface.vertices[k].x, rTile.surface.vertices[k].y, rTile.surface.vertices[k].z);
                }

                GL11.glEnd();

                //if (rTile.texturePos != null)
                    //if (rTile.texturePos.pos != -1)
                        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem occurs in the RENDERING TILES part. Those are without a texture (for now) and I want them to be just colored squares - red (for lava) and blue (for water). Colors are taken from a static var and are proper (I checked that by System.out.ln(tile.color.getRed()......  -  the output was 0,0,255). Here is the static var:

```
/* TILES */
//ShallowWater
public static ColorStruct V00255 = new ColorStruct(new Color(0, 0, 255), "Tile", "ShallowWater"); //Pure blue
```

The output looks like this: [Rendered scene](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/225/probvx.jpg/)

The white fields are water - they're supposed to be blue!

An additional problem is the FPS - as you can see on the screen, it's 41. Before adding the multiple glEnable and glDisables of textures in the rendering section, FPS were 60. Are those multiple enables and disables causing this and can it be avoided?

I'm a complete newbie at openGL and this is also my first question here so please forgive me if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glColor3ub` takes unsigned bytes. Maybe you are using signed bytes? Have you tried `glColor3ub(0,0,255)` or `glColor3f(0,0,1)`? If it does work, make sure `getRedByte` etc. returns correct values.

To improve performance:

- If your scene is mostly static use [display lists](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_displaylist.html).
- Optimize you OpenGL calls. Avoid `glDisable`/`glEnable` and `glBindTexture`. Modern graphic cards are really fast as long as you are not changing state a lot. You can avoid `glEnable`/`glDisable` by using empty white texture. `glBindTexture` can be avoided by using [texture atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas).
- If display lists are too slow use [VBO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_Buffer_Object)s.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try the idea of empty white texture, it sounds nice! I tried to make atlases few days ago but failed miserably so I resigned. Now, however, I think I know why I failed so I will try that again. Is it possible to render part of the scene in a static mode (display lists) and the rest of it dynamically?
The colors were fine with the same values before I started switching between enable/disable inside rendering function. glColor3ub(0, 0, 255) gives the same effect, same as glColor3f(0, 0, 1). getBlueByte returns 255, the rest 0, so it seems correct.

Comment: @Myzreal: If I remember correctly using texture 0 (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE2D,0)`) will have the same affect as white texture (at least in your case). From what I understand it should solve your problem. You can use display lists to render only static parts of your scene. You can render the rest normally.

Comment: I managed to use texture atlases and use an empty white texture, but not using the texture 0. I just added a white square to the end of my atlas and use that, so I can only use glBind once, in the init section. I believe it gives the same effect? The colors however are still not there - the "textureless" water is now textured white and I cannot get the texture to be colored. The other textures, like walls, ground and ceiling, cannot be colored either. How can I color  textures?